# Authentication System with Challenge-Response

Tags: java, authentication, challenge-response

i am very new to Java and very new to Programming. My task is to build a Authentication System with at least two users and also a Challenge-Response-Request.
I generated Hashes of the Passwords using MD5 and a Salt, i just cant find a way to ask if the entered password by the client is equal to the generated hash of the password. Also i dont know how to tell my client what the salt is.

This is what i build so far.

````
Server
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class server {

    ServerSocket serversocket;
    Socket client;

    BufferedReader input;
    PrintWriter output;

    public void start() throws IOException{
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
        System.out.println("Connection Starting on port:" + serversocket.getLocalPort() );
        //make connection to client on port specified


        //accept connection from client
        client = serversocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Waiting for connection from client");

        try {
            logInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public static void main1(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        String pass1 = "karotte";
        String pass2 = "tomate";
        
        String algorithm = "MD5";
        byte[] salt = createSalt();
        System.out.println("Bob MD5 Hash: "+ generateHash1(pass1, algorithm, salt));
        System.out.println("Alice MD5 Hash: "+ generateHash2(pass2, algorithm, salt));
        
    }

    private static 
    String generateHash1(String pass1, String algorithm, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(salt);
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(pass1.getBytes());
        return bytesToStringHex(hash);
    }


    static String generateHash2(String pass2, String algorithm, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(salt);
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(pass2.getBytes());
        return bytesToStringHex(hash);
        
    }

    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToStringHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static byte[] createSalt() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[5];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
    }

    public void logInfo() throws Exception{
        //open buffered reader for reading data from client

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        
        
        String username = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("username" + username);
        String password = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("password" + password);

        //open printwriter for writing data to client
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));


        if(username.equals("Bob") &&password.equals()){
            output.println("Welcome, " + username);
        }else 
        if{
         (username.equals("Alice) &&password.equals()){
            output.println("Welcome, "+ username);
        }else{
            output.println("Login Failed");
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        server server = new server();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

} 

Client
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class client {


    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    PrintWriter output;

    public void startClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        //Create socket connection
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9090);

        //create printwriter for sending login to server
        output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        //prompt for user name
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");

        //send user name to server
        output.println(username);

        //prompt for password
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password");

        //send password to server
        output.println(password);
        output.flush();

        //create Buffered reader for reading response from server
        read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        //read response from server
        String response = read.readLine();
        System.out.println("This is the response: " + response);

        //display response
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response);
    }



    public static void main(String args[]){
        client client = new client();
        try {
            client.startClient();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Why does the client need to know what the salt is?

Comment: Because the Response would be Hash = (challenge + password). So wouldnt the Salt be the challenge?

Answer (score 0):

If you are about a client/server connection why not use SSl and X509 certificate based mutual authentication?
It's easy to set up and puts an extra security in.